# I change the format of a list with floating values to sequence of tuples in PYTHON. But the output i get is not exactly the same

Tags: python, list, floating-point, tuples

I have a LIST in python, mentioned below. I am trying to convert it from list format to SEQUENCE OF TUPLES. I am able to convert it into a tuple but unable to get the desired output. Can someone please go through the code I have mentioned below ? There should not be any strings in the output like I have in the list. SO i convert it into tuples without string in the output.

Expected output = `((4.1,), (4.2,), (4.3,), (4.4,), (4.5,), (4.6,), (4.7,))`

**sample code to convert**

```
List_to_be_converted = sf
sf = ['4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4', '4.5', '4.6', '4.7']
convert = tuple((float(x[0]), ) for x in sf)
```

**output after running the code**

convert = `((4.0,), (4.0,), (4.0,), (4.0,), (4.0,), (4.0,), (4.0,))`

I am unable to see the decimal values of the output. What can be the possible error? please
Thank you a lot for your time

Comment: This can be resolved by making a [mcve] (try removing each part of the code to see if the problem persists, etc.)

Comment: `x[0]` is going to be the first character of every string: `4`.

Comment: `tuple([(float(x), ) for x in sf])`

Answer (score 3):

```
sf = ['4.1', '4.2', '4.3', '4.4', '4.5', '4.6', '4.7']
convert = tuple([(float(x), ) for x in sf]) 
print (convert)
```

if you have not DOT separator for digit, you need replace other character on dot

```
sf = ['4!1', '4!2', '4!3', '4!4', '4!5', '4!6', '4!7']
convert = tuple([(float(x.replace('!','.')), ) for x in sf]) 
print (convert)
```

i have '!' as like separator for digits

Comment: what if i have certain float values with COMMA  as separator   ** sf = ['4,12', '4,32', '4,3', '4,46', '4,53', '4,63', '4,70'] **   how can i convert it into list of float values as DOT   ** ['4.12', '4.32', '4.3', '4.46', '4.53', '4.63', '4.70']** ? thank you

Comment: this is also easy: in cycle 'x' is a string, string has function 'replace' for change all some character on other one. for example, s1 = s1.replace('!', '?') you will get new string where all char ! will be replace on ?. so, about your task, you need change x on x.replace(',' , '.') and you get ['4.12' , '4.32'... ]